# Apple Reject "Explain the use of the AppTrackingTransparency framework in the purpose string."

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store, apptrackingtransparency

Apple Reject my app with feedback that says I need to change my AppTrackingTransparency description. My app doesn't use personalized ads or IDFA. This AppTrackingTransparency identifier for me is for Firebase Messaging that allows us to send them personal message like verify phone number etc. It says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14) that Firebase in App Messaging need to request App Tracking Permission on iOS 14.

This is the current description on my AppTrackingTransparency in info.plist and this one got rejected.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>One of our third party library (firebase) requires tracking usage. We personally do not track the user's activity.</string>
```

Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the    AppTrackingTransparency framework, but doesn’t sufficiently
> explain    the use of the AppTrackingTransparency framework in the
> purpose    string.
> To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used,    all permission request alerts need to specify how your app
> will use    the requested information.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist    file to specify why
> your app needs access to the user's
> AppTrackingTransparency framework. Make sure the purpose string
> includes an example of how the user's data will be used.
> You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list    editor in Xcode.

I plan on using this description

> This identifier require users permission to enable the
> firebase messaging to send targeted and contextual messages to nudge
> them to complete key in-app actions like verifying their phone number. We personally do not track
> the user's activity

Is there anyone who have experience or suggestion on this matter? so I can pass in Apple's approval, I need a description that will pass on Apple's approval.

Comment: That description still seems quite complicated and is difficult to understand. Does fire base messaging use the IDFA?  If not then you don’t need to request app tracking permission. Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14

Comment: @Paulw11 do you know how to remove the AppTrackingTransparency or to not include in the app?

Comment: If your app (and none of the included frameworks) doesn't use the IDFA you can just remove the info.plist key and don't make the tracking request.  If Apple detects that your cod is using the IDFA when you submit then you will get notified and you either need to provide a meaningful tracking description or remove the offending code/framework. Stating that "we don't track the user's activity" is *not helpful or informative*. The app tracking message is for the user, not Apple. The user doesn't see a difference between your app and any service your app uses. They see that your app wants to track

Comment: If firebase needs the IDFA (and I can't see how it would given the function you say you are using) then you need to explain what exactly will happen. "XYZApp will provide your phone number and your tracking identifier to Google so they can associate your advertising identifier with other apps that also use Google services"

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please explain to me more about IDFA because I don't understand it even though I read about IDFA and how did it use it in the app. Is it like unique id that identify the user so they can deliver or send personal message?

Comment: No, the IDFA is an identifier that is intended for advertising tracking.  All apps on a device get the same value for the IDFA. The idea was to let advertising frameworks correlate activity in different apps I order to deliver more targeted apps. Apple has now said the user needs to approve such tracking. Without approval apps do not get a value when they request the IDFA so they cannot track the user.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by explaining what the use of AppTrackingTransparency in my info. plist, and I revise and use the description that I plan to use, It is in the question that i submit.

Comment: My app is also rejected because of the reason. We are also using Firebase Messaging. Could you please share what is the info description that is in your app which is approved by Apple? Appreciate your help.